# Login page using oracle sys.user$ for PHP

Tags: php, oracle, authentication, oracle-call-interface

I need to create the login page that will use username and password from `sys.user$`, but when want to login the login is failed.

But if I use the table that I created it can.

```
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$password=$_REQUEST['password'];

if(!empty($name) && !empty($password)){

   $sqlCheck=OCIParse($c,"SELECT NAME, PASSWORD FROM sys.user$ 
                           WHERE NAME='$name'
                             AND PASSWORD='$password'");

   OCIExecute($sqlCheck,OCI_DEFAULT);

   while(OCIFetch($sqlCheck)){
     $db_name = OCIResult($sqlCheck, "NAME");
     $db_password = OCIResult($sqlCheck, "PASSWORD");
   }

   if($db_name != $name && $db_password != $password){
     echo "<script>window.location.href='../index.php?page=login&error=1';</script>";
     exit();
   } else {
     $_SESSION['verify_name'] = $name;
     echo "<script>window.location.href='../index.php?page=please_verify';</script>";
     exit();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are not using `SYS` user for your application,

You need a privilege to access `SYS.USER$` from `SYS` user. Check whether or not you have privilege to access the table.

Solution would be, `grant select privilege` from `SYS` user to whatever user you are using in your application to connect to the database.

Comment: I use sys.user$ for the application. If I copy the password Hash, and paste on password field at login form, the login is success. But, if I use my real password the login is invalid.

Comment: I think you should check the password encryption part in your application. Because Oracle encrypts the password and saves it. And if you dont encrypt and compare the passwords wont be matched. Either encrypt the password and match or decrypt the password hash and compare.  Also let me know the Oracle database version you are using.

Comment: version of oracle database is 11g. Password version 10g and 11g.

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment, just check with the encryption and decryption of password. If the password is not being encrypted before matching then it might cause your code to fail.